# How to stop iOS app from updating without permission

Tags: ios, auto-update

More than once, I've unlocked my iPad to see an app and a folder immediately show the updating symbol.  I don't know which app in the folder is updating, but the one not in the folder is Memrise.

I looked in the preferences, and Memrise is not even listed in the long list of apps that have settings.  There is no settings icon on the main screen of Memrise, and I can't log in until I look up my password.  This never happened before the iOS 10 upgrade.

What might this be and how to stop it?

Comment: When a folder shows the updating symbol (the circle that fills up) you can tap on the folder to view which app is being updated, or go to the App Store app and tap on the Updates tab.

Comment: It updates too fast for that to do any good.

Comment: All of your updates are listed in the App Store, most recent first.

Answer (score 1):

Apps cannot update themselves. The only way for an app to update is through the App Store.

To disable the App Store automatically downloading updates, open the Settings app, tap on iTunes & App Store, then toggle Updates off under Automatic Downloads (so it is white, not green).

Note this will disable automatic updating for *all* apps, not just specific ones. You cannot disable automatic updating on a per-app basis.

When automatic updates are off, you need to open the App Store to update your apps. Go to the Updates tab and tap Update across from each app listed to update it.

Comment: probably within seconds of each other....

Comment: When I first saw your answer pop up, yours said "40 seconds ago" and mine said "1 minute ago", so yeah. lol

Comment: Your answer is more complete than mine so I'll delete mine.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the case.  I have had to select update on MANY apps often, both before and after the IOS upgrade.  This never happened before for any app, it has only happened for memrise and that folder since, and I have not changed any settings, though apparently IOS did.  (Sierra upgrade on MacBook also set several prefs back to default.)

Comment: Even if Automatic Updates are enabled, it only occurs a few times a day. You still have the ability to manually trigger any update that is pending in the App Store. Did you look at the Automatic Updates setting and see if that's enabled?

Comment: Automatic updates was on, but the text under it says it is for _new_ purchases made on _other_ devices.  I do not think I turned that on, and since this has only happened in IOS 10, why would Apple change that on us?  AND, if it is on, why are these two similar apps, memrise and duolingo, the only ones that are doing this?  I have seen the badge saying updates are available and gone to the app store to see them waiting for me to accept them.

Comment: The text about purchases is referring to the first three items (Music/Apps/Books & Audiobooks). As far as I know, simply upgrading iOS should not have changed this preference, though it's possible something glitched. As far as it just being those two apps, I would wager there's been others that you just haven't seen it happening to, but as I said before, automatic updates is not immediate - if you go to the Updates tab before an update is automatically downloaded, you still have the ability to manually trigger its download.

Comment: How would "automatic" be delayed for all but two apps, both of which update as soon as screen is unlocked?  In any case, I turned it off and it stopped happening (or else those two have had no updates since.)  As for "haven't seen," that's unlikely since the app (or folder is replaced by an obvious timer icon and made unusable during the update.  As for changing settings, yeah, it's weird, but the MacOS recent update did put several of my preferences back to factory default.

Comment: Although the answer doesn't explain why it only happened for only two apps, it does describe the way to stop it, which I did, since I don't want any apps to autoupdate.